# Compare the limit of a sequence with the upper bound of the sequence as in Dominated convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Recall Dominated Convergence Theorem: Let $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of measurable functions s.th. $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise. Suppose there exists a non-negative integrable function $g$ with $|f_n|\leq g$ for all $n\geq 1$. Then
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_Sf_nd\mu=\int_S fd\mu.
\end{equation}

My question is that: Is it true $f\leq g$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. For all $x$ and $n$, $$f_n(x)\le \lvert f_n(x)\rvert\le g(x)$$ Therefore, for all $x$, $$f(x)=\limsup_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)\le g(x)$$